# Insert data into specific table (sqlalchemy)

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy

It's pretty easy to insert data into a database by using sqlalchemy.

```
address.name = 'Joe'
address.age = 26
session.add(address)
```

But actually I have three tables - how can I specify the table I want to insert my data in?

Comment: You mean three similar tables?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the sql expression language to add the new row:

```
engine.execute(table_addresses.insert(), name='Joe', age=20)
engine.execute(table_contacts.insert(), email='joe@something.com', cellnumber='267534320')
```

Normaly I use the ORM but in my case it is more convinient.

Comment: If you are using a session, do `session.execute(table_addresses.insert().values(name='Joe', age=20))` instead.

Comment: how is this preferable over using session ? if the table is dynamically created recently will `engine.execute`  work ?

Answer (score 14):

You will probably want to look at the [sqlalchemy ORM tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html).

To get you started though, I suspect you are going to want to set up something like the following.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'addresses'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
```

Now since it appears you already know how to get a session, you could just do this

```
address = Address('Joe', 26)
session.add(address)
session.commit() # This will do the actual database insertion
```

Although it is possible that you could probably just try to do it on the fly, it probably wouldn't make your life easier, as you'd still have to tell it what objects relate to integers, strings, etc, to map to the database table.

Comment: Thats also the way I add data to my database. Assumed there are more than one tables in the database how can I specify to add the data to the table "Contacts" instead of "adresses"?

Comment: As mentioned above you could use `__tablename__ = 'addresses'` you specify the table name `addresses`. Are you instead rather dealing with a few identical tables that have different names?

Comment: What I'd probably recommend, if you have different tables, have different classes mapping them. The `__tablename__` will be used to tell it the actual table in the database to match to. For example, based on your `contacts` example, you'd probably replace the `class` line with something like `class Contact(Base):` and the `__tablename__` line with `__tablename__ = 'contacts'`. 

Are you instead trying to fire them into different tables dynamically on the fly?

Comment: Yes, I want to add them into different tables dynamically

Comment: Im not in a mapped class when I try to add the data.

Comment: This answer misinterprets the question.